# CSS positioning inside div

Tags: css

I am using a div with 2 elements inside and I want to position my 1st element to be vertically aligned top and 2nd element to the bottom of the div. The div is the right portion of my page and equal to the height of my main content.

```
#right {
    float:right;
    width: 19%;
    background:#FF3300;
    margin-left:2px;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -100%;
}
#right .top {
    display:block;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}
#right .bottom {    
    bottom:0px;
    display:block;
    background-color:#FFCCFF;
    height:60px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="right">
    <span class="top">Top element</span>
    <span class="bottom"><img src="images/logo_footer1.gif" width="57" height="57" align="left" class="img">&nbsp;<img src="images/logo_footer2.gif" width="57" height="57" align="right" class="img"></span>
</div>
```

I want the right div to be like this:
[alt text http://christianruado.comuf.com/element.png](http://christianruado.comuf.com/element.png)

Comment: You might also want to try checking out/posting this to http://doctype.com/

Answer (score 7):

If you specify `position: relative` for `#right`, and then `position: absolute` for the two internal elements, you should be able to use top/left/bottom/right attributes to achieve the effect you want.

Comment: The problem was the right container is inside the wrapper, and overflow is set to hidden. so the bottom portion of the right container is hidden when it overflow to the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
   #right {
         position:relative; <-- add this
        float:right;
        width: 19%;
        background:#FF3300;
        margin-left:2px;
        padding-bottom: 100%;
        margin-bottom: -100%;

    }

}
#right .top {
     position:absolute; <-- add this
     top: 0px; <-- and this
    display:block;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

    #right .bottom {   
          position:absolute: <-- add this.
        bottom:0px;
        display:block;
        background-color:#FFCCFF;
        height:60px;

    }
```

Adding `position:relative;` to the parent and `position:absolute;` with `top` and `bottom` will tell your spans that they're meant to be positioned absolutely within your parent and force them to stick to the top and bottom of your div.

Comment: The problem was the right container is inside the wrapper, and overflow is set to hidden. so the bottom portion of the right container is hidden when it overflow to the wrapper.

Comment: Ah, well that would definitely cause some problems. Hope it works for you now :)

Answer (score 0):

Make `#right {position:relative}`

Make `#right .top {position:absolute, top:0}`

Make `#right .bottom {position:absolute, bottom:0}`