# CSS image positioning inside <div>

Tags: html, css

I have been making a website and I want an opening image to be found on my screen.  The problem is that I have the picture I want to use but it is to big for the space I want it to fit in.  This could be solved 2 ways: I could scale the image to fit in the Div or I could position the image inside the div to show the essential parts of my picture.  Ideally I would like the second option but I am ok with the first. I believe that I have done sufficient research on this question and this question is not like these:[First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635957/css-positioning-inside-div), [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180462/css-positioning-inside-a-div).  I have also done my own experiments on this problem but using the position property and clear divs these have not worked to my satisfaction.

Here is what i believe to be the essential code for this question:

HTML:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1> New IQ Test </h1>
    <p>Take our quiz</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
    /*padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 10px;*/
    height: 500px;
    display:block;
    background-image: url(http://bit.ly/1IMUMR0);
    width: 100%;
    /*padding-top: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -30px;*/
    text-align: center;
    color:white;
}

.jumbotron h1 {
    padding-top: 150px;
    font-weight: normal;
    opacity: 100;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px black;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

The image I am using is not owned by me. I realize this is illegal.  I am NOT going to put this web page out for general use so it us ok if I use this image.  All your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.jumbotron {
/*padding-left: 50px;
padding-right: 10px;*/
background-size: 100% 100%;
/*background-size: cover;*/
height: 500px;
display:block;
background-image: url(http://bit.ly/1IMUMR0);
width: 100%;
/*padding-top: 100px;
position: absolute;
bottom: -30px;*/
text-align: center;
color:white;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: contain;` or maybe some other value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size: cover;
```

Will just show part of the image as you resize the browser.

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

Will auto-size the image on browser resize so the full image is always visible.

Answer (score 0):

I would scale it down with CSS myself, but if you're fine with just a portion of the image showing, then why don't you crop it? You'll get the affect you're looking for, and your asset size will decrease.